# How can I build a recurrent neural network to deal with time series to get a single continuous value？

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

[image: the expected model]

I want to build a RNN with tensorflow, and it can convert a time series to a single continuous value. For example, the input time series `x` is `[x1,x2,x3,x4,...,xt]=[1,2,3,4,...,100]`, and the corresponding output `y` is `98.5`, just like score the time series. I found this figure in Yoshua Bengio's deep learning book, and this RNN model is what I want. Is there any useful reading material can help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the rnn section in book << TensorFlow for machine intelligence >> which descibes different functionalities of rnn models with sample code